# IndexError: list index out of range ( Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The python code snippet is:

```
n=int(input())
a=list(map(int,input().split()))
check=[0 for i in range(n)]


for i in range(1,n):
    temp=1
    ii=i
    while ((a[ii]-a[ii-1]) <= 2 ) and (ii < n):
        temp+=1
        ii+=1

    if a[i-1]-a[i-2] <= 2 and i>1:
        check[i-1]=check[i-2]
    else:
        check[i-1]=check[i-1]+temp
```

Input and the error message:

```
5
1 2 5 6 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CoronavirusSpread.py", line 11, in <module>
    while ((a[ii]-a[ii-1]) <= 2 ) and (ii < n):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
while ((a[ii]-a[ii-1]) <= 2 ) and (ii < n):
```

to:

```
while (ii < n) and ((a[ii]-a[ii-1]) <= 2 ) :
```

when ii crosses n, a[ii] gives the error as conditions are evaluated in order..

Answer (score 0):

This loop:

```
while ((a[ii]-a[ii-1]) <= 2 ) and (ii < n):
    temp+=1
    ii+=1
```

will result in `ii == n`, which is beyond the list size and accessing `a[ii]` will give you `IndexError`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to access the index 0 in while loop at first iteration which does not exists. Try the following

for i in range(1,n):
    if i!=1:
      #your code
    else:
      continue